# Why does alert() execute before my $.each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) with a fairly large form (88 fields) that was converted to html5 from a fillable PDF by [this](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdfform-to-html5-converter) nice online tool. It works great, but seems to be acting more asynchronously than I want it to.

In the code that runs in response to clicking the `Submit` button for the form, if any validation errors were detected, I want to display the messages and pop up an alert telling the user to correct the errors shown and try again. The code looks like this:

```
        success: function() {
            const OSHform=$("form").eq(0);
            if (OSHform.valid()) {
                top.document.location.href = "/Adsentry/completed";
            }
            else {
                OSH.placeMessages();
                alert("Fields did not validate. Please fix the highlighted fields and try again");
            }
        }
```

Where:

```
OSH.placeMessages = function() {
    $('div[id^="form"].error').each(function(index) {
        let me = $( this )
        let labelid = me.attr("id");
        let inputid = labelid.replace("-error", "");
        let input_elem = $("#" + inputid);
        let heightnum = 1 * input_elem.css("height").replace("px", "");
        let topnum = 1 * input_elem.css("top").replace("px","");
        if (input_elem.attr("name") === "JR DOB") {
            topnum -= heightnum;
        }
        let leftnum = 1 * input_elem.css("left").replace("px", "");
        let widthnum = 1 * input_elem.css("width").replace("px", "");
        me.css("position", "absolute");
        me.css("top", (topnum + heightnum - 6) + "px");
        me.css("left", (leftnum + 10) + "px");
        me.css("color", "red");
        me.css("z-index", 1000);
        me.css("display", "block");
    });
}
```

But when I submit a form with validation errors, the alert pops up first, before any errors are displayed in the form. Then when I click OK to dismiss the alert, the invalid fields get highlighted and error messages get filled in, just as they should. How can I make the alert wait until after the messages are displayed? I didn't expect that the `$.each()` loop would go off to async land and let the `alert()` run ahead on the main thread...

Of course the real question is how do I get it to behave the way I expect? It doesn't seem like $.each returns a promise such that I could put the `alert()` in a function called when the promise is resolved...

Comment: Try `setTimeout(()=>alert("Fields did not validate. Please fix the highlighted fields and try again"));`

Comment: You might try `Promise.resolve().then(alert("..."))` to let the repaint happen

Comment: Alternatively put your error text right in your page somewhere; `alert()` is kind-of 1997.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, that did the trick, thanks! Now as to why it's necessary - it came as a total surprise to me.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, but where does Promise come from? AFAIK, $.each doesn't return a promise, I think it returns the jQuery object, doesn't it? Regarding 1997, that was a very good year, the year my horse was foaled :-) But seriously, it's quite a busy form, and it would be a nuisance to write code to put the message in a pop-out box that would clearly stand out, with an OK button to dismiss it - especially when alert() behaves exactly the way I'd want that box to do.

Comment: No, `Promise.resolve()` gives you an already-resolved Promise instance. So it will run the `.then()` callback *almost* immediately. It's essentially like a very short timer.

Comment: @Pointy I'd ask you the same question, why is it necessary to worry about the timing? What should have alerted (haha) me to the fact that my $.each loop would run asynchronously such that I'd need to do something special to cause the alert() to wait until it completed?

Comment: Because you're allowing the browser to act on the just-completed code that updated the DOM. The browser is running your alert *before* it repaints. By doing the alert a very short interval later in a different task cycle, you're fixing that.

Comment: And the `$.each()` loop is indeed synchronous. The browser however batches up DOM changes until it absolutely needs to do a render.

Comment: @Pointy WOW! Thanks very much! Guess I need to learn a lot more about how browsers work. Any good references on that, to help avoid similar surprises in the future?

Comment: There are references about the different "task queues" out there. This particular trick has several similar uses, like trying to do something in a "blur" event handler can run into similar issues for example.

Comment: Blocking the user flow with an alert is not very user friendly. Consider a non-blocking message that slides in and out automatically, such as https://github.com/ducdhm/bootstrap-msg

Comment: @Peter Thoeny I think that in this case it is perfectly appropriate. The user attempted to submit the form - i.e. they thought their flow was done. But it wasn't valid. So the alert tells them they've got more work to do before they can successfully submit the form.

Comment: An alert is a modal dialog that interrupts the flow, it's bad UI. If you don't like a message fading in & out (we primates are drown to anything that moves in the peripheral vision), then consider a non-blocking popup below the submit button showing the errors. My 2c

Comment: @Peter Thoeny I'm sorry, but "bad UI" doesn't mean anything without a reason. It seems you're saying it interrupts the flow. I said the flow was already interrupted by the user, who said he was done working on the form and submitted it. And you reply "bad UI", it interrupts the flow. We must be speaking different languages or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to allow the browser to repaint first.

```js
setTimeout(()=>alert("Fields did not validate. Please fix the highlighted fields and try again"));
```